# Hibernate: How to make Hibernate delete records from child table when deleting parent if child is linked to parent with many-to-one?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, cascade

Lets say I have two tables - "child" and "parent" with many-to-one relation. What I need is to delete child entries if parent record is deleted.

It is not a problem if I link child table from parent by creating one-to-many association in parent.hbm and set cascade="all-delete-orphan".

The problem is I don't want one-to-many relation on the parent side, so I created many-to-one on the child side. The reason for that is child table is pretty big and I don't want to extract hundreds of records every time I use parent. 
So my configuration looks like this:

child.hbm:

```
<many-to-one name="parent" class="com.example.Parent" column="parentid"/>
```

while parent.hbm has no associations with child.

The question is: **How to make Hibernate delete records from child table when deleting a parent if a child is linked to a parent with many-to-one?**

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use a lazy one-to-many in the parent and just use the cascade option? When you use the parent you won't load the child.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I am afraid it will bring confusion to the structure. I will need to add "Set<Child> children" field to parent class which should not be used anywhere in the code, only for hibernate cascade deletion. Do you think it is ok?

Comment: Yes, it is a logical relation. After all the parent-children relationship does exists. Make the setter private if you don't want to expose it.

Comment: Ok, I will use that if there is no other options. Thank you.

Comment: Btw looks like it doesn't allow private setters. Oh well...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of options:

- add the one-to-many to the parent with cascading delete, but mitigate the performance loss using lazy loading.
- use a [Hibernate Interceptor](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html) (or an aspect in an AOP environment) to detect parent record deletions and delete children.

Personally I would favour the first option, as it lets your data model more closely reflect the real relationships in your data.

**Edit:** there's a third option, but it's not pleasant - use a database trigger, and flush your Hibernate cache (or use a non-caching session).

Comment: I was almost compelled to DV after reading your trigger option! I'm glad you didn't include that as a real solution.

Comment: any update on doing this via Hibernate? Does anyone know if this could be supported at some point?